# Converter PDF em texto com Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Bem, tenho um arquivo PDF que está em um site, gostaria de saber como pegar o texto desse PDF e colocá-lo em uma variável.

Acessar o site com o PDF eu sei, minha dificuldade está em converter esse PDF em texto, ou simplesmente copiar o texto.

Estou utilizando Python 3.x

Answer (score 2):

Sendo um PDF uma imagem, para extrair os textos é necessário um pacote OCR (é preciso ter em mente que esses pacotes podem não ter 100% de acerto), há vários deles em python, para o que vc deseja tem um bem interessante que funciona no python 2.7 e 3.4, [textract.](http://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Veja um exemplo:

```
import textract
text = textract.process("orcamento.pdf")
print (text)  

Clicar para incluir o cabeçalho

EXEMPLO DE ORÇAMENTO: Exemplos de Itens Detalhados
OBSERVAÇÃO : Este é somente um exemplo. Nem todos os orçamentos terão todos os exemplos listados abaixo. Favor usar somente os itens que dizem
respeito ao seu projeto proposto.

I. SALÁRIOS
Diretor Executivo
Diretor de Projeto
Contador
Editor Sênior
Editor

Salário Anual
5000
4000
2000
750
500

Porcentagem
50%
100%
50%
20%
45%
```

Utilizei [esse pdf](http://www.ned.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/BGSample-PO-0712.pdf) para o exemplo, claro que copiei somente parte do resultado, apenas para demonstração.

Obs.:

- No seu caso, vc teria que baixar o pdf para um diretorio local e realizar o processo do exemplo.
- Para instalar no python 3, [veja esse link](http://www.tysonmaly.com/installing-textract-for-python-3/).

Comment: textract.exceptions.ShellError: The command `pdftotext oi.pdf -` failed with exit code 127
------------- stdout -------------
------------- stderr -------------

Comment: porqueeeeeeeeeee :(

Comment: @Luanpedro Seria interessante vc apresentar o contexto em que isso acontece, que tal mostrar um fragmento de codigo?

Comment: Meu cod > https://pastebin.com/pdMbxhXa
Boletim usado > https://www.sendspace.com/file/08khoa
ERRO: http://prntscr.com/kwg16g

Meu tópico sobre isso > https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/329889/pegar-valores-em-boletim-usando-python-ocr

Comment: @Luanpedro Putz... ficar indo atras de imagens é complicado, melhor colocar aqui. Mas se arrumar um tempo vou verificar. :-)